# Show document structure in AucTeX

Tags: auctex, editors

I'm writing a large document using AucTeX (in Linux), and I'm getting lost in the document. I previously used TexMaker and it has a vertical panel that shows you the document structure to navigate it easier. I would like to know if there's something similar in AucTeX, to show the structure in a different buffer, or something like that. I have already seen

[Navigate a TeX code using emacs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66166/navigate-a-tex-code-using-emacs)

to navigate, but I would like something that shows the structure. Does it exist?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an outline window: `C-c =`, it displays the table of contents. You can navigate inside this buffer to any headline.

When I installed AucTeX and RefTeX years ago, I put -- among others -- those lines into my .emacs:

```
(require 'reftex)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex) ; with AUCTeX LaTeX mode
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t) ; Anleitung S. 4
```

Comment: I get `C-c = is undefined` and tht's weird because I'm seeing RefTex is built within Emacs after version 24.3, I have version 24.3.1

Comment: RefTeX has nothing to do with it, sorry

Comment: @AlexandreRademaker  Ask a new question, not here in the comments.